# Building DLLs that use other DLLs in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to parallelize our build process in Visual Studio 2005 to take advantage of our multi-core hardware. Simplifying things a bit, I've got two DLLs and an application. DLL A has no dependencies. DLL B uses certain functions defined in DLL A. The application uses functions defined in both.

I thought I should be able to build A and B in parallel, because you shouldn't need to resolve symbols until you link the application. However, when I remove DLL B's project dependency on A, I get errors like the following:

```
YFindReplaceWidget.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual unsigned long __thiscall CORBBaseComponent::GetRefCount(void)const " (__imp_?GetRefCount@CORBBaseComponent@@UBEKXZ)
```

Is there a way to resolve these errors so I can build these DLLs in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

That's... a really weird thought pattern. DLL's are nothing but EXE's with a different extensions, they need full linking information to be built.

As long as your build is a chain like that (app->b->a), they can't be built in parallel.

Comment: Do DLL's have program entry points like EXE's? I had thought they were more like libraries that couldn't actually run on their own.

Comment: Well technically EXE's are DLL's with a `WinMain` function requirement. DLL's do actually have an "entry point", `DllMain`, but it's somewhat different. Still, my point stands, building a DLL is not at all different from building an EXE, it can't be done with incomplete linker information.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know the technical difference like that! :)

Comment: Interesting. I was used to thinking of them more like .so files under Unix, which don't require full linking.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft officially introduced a multiprocessor built option in VS2008. It will allow the build to start multiple compilers for the same project. The easy solution is just upgrade to the latest version of Visual Studio.

If you are stuck on VS2005, then it is actually available there as well, but not officially supported. Just add /MP as an additional compiler option.

http://blog.280z28.org/archives/2007/10/17/ (Advices you NOT to use it on your buildserver)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx